# How can i deploy a PHP web application in subdomain using .htaccess permission

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, subdomain

I have deployed a PHP web application on my host (root of my host) now i want to install a web analytic php web application in a folder called "stat" (in the root of my host as a sub domain) but ".htaccess" file in the root of first PHP application does not allow to access "stat" folder how can i config ".htaccess" file to allow map stat.mydomain.com to "stat" folder.

This is ".htaccess" file located in the root of my host:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

I wish i can describe my problem clearly. please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this maybe: `RewriteRule ^/(subdomain)/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`? Not really sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically that says that requests for `http://subdomain.domain.com/` will be retrieved from `http://domain.com/subdomain/`.

Comment: If I understood right, that folder is defined in the virtual host entries in `httpd.conf`, not in .htaccess. For example: `<VirtualHost *>` `ServerName stat.domain.com` `DocumentRoot /home/httpd/htdocs/stat/` `</VirtualHost>`, where `/home/httpd/htdocs/` is the DocumentRoot of the primary domain.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first I hope you have a `VirtualHost` entry in your `httpd.conf` for subdomain `stat.mydomain.com` as commented by `faa`.

Once you have that working change your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` with this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?qa-rewrite=$0 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```